# Netlogo: To make and mark the specific location

Tags: netlogo

I'm still new in Netlogo. This is my solution for final year project. I need to do path planning for homogeneous coordinate.

But at first, I need to do the position in patch. Means there will be at least 3 coordinate that arranged by myself not random. After that, I need to mark it red color/circle/dot.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you're asking. Would you significantly expand on this, by editing your question, and showing the relevant part of the code you have? If you are getting unexpected output, please show what you are getting and what you wanted, and your theory as to why they are different. What is "path planning"? What is "position in patch"? If these are whole features, then the question needs narrowing down a great deal.

Comment: Yes. You right. I will adjust my question.